# I can not declare bigint variable

Tags: sql-server

In Sql server I can't declare a variable with *bigint* data type. My *Mobile* column has *bigint* data type. it's give me error *varchar* not convert to *bigint* when i use procedure.

When i write `Mobile=cast(@Mobile as varchar)` it works fine

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Suggestion]
        @FirstName varchar(255),
        @MiddleName varchar(255),
        @LastName varchar(255),
        @Mobile Bigint

AS
BEGIN
 SELECT
    *
     FROM dbo.Contacts
     WHERE
     (
       Mobile =@Mobile 
     )
END
```

**Table Structure**

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Contacts]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] (
[ContactId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[Name] varchar(100) NOT NULL ,
[FamilyHeadId] int NULL ,
[Addressold] ntext NULL ,
[Mobile] bigint NULL ,
```

*Calling*

```
Get_Suggestion 'John','Doe','Patel',999999999
```

Comment: check your mobile column data type

Comment: are you sure. Check your table DDL again

Comment: How are your calling the SP?

Comment: @wewesthemenace - I also thought it might be related to application passing a varchar to a `bigint` @mobile parameter however "When i write Mobile=cast(@Mobile as varchar) it works fine" suggests that it's related to the sql query and the table and its type

Comment: @ughai, oh I see. Must be the table then.

Comment: Just tried running your SP, can't replicate the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `Mobile` is not an integer but a `VARCHAR` in your table and hence sql server tries to convert `Mobile` column to `BIGINT` when you compare with `@Mobile` in your `WHERE Mobile =@Mobile`

```
Mobile=cast(@Mobile as varchar)
```

The above works because now there is no implicit conversion of `Mobile` column to `bigint`.

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question, everything should work fine. Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e43f8/2)

Comment: Mobile column data type is BIGINT

Comment: Are you sure? can you post your table structure?

Comment: I have added my structure.

Comment: Check this. your table above with the procedure works fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e43f8/2

Answer (score 1):

I ran the script you have provided in this Question, it works very well in my Local.

i guess you are making mistake in code while passing parameter, check your datatype while passing the parameter, that should be the only possibility of giving an error.